# Access is denied: pip freeze > requirements.txt

Tags: python, heroku, anaconda

I tried to run the below command on my virtual env window 10.
`pip freeze > requirements.txt`, but I get an `access denied response`

I also tried this pip freeze > requirements.txt --user but I got the same response. what could be wrong and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

perhaps you don't have the write permissions. Try to delete "requirements.txt" file (if ones already exists) and run that command "pip freeze > requirements.txt" again. Also check your permission via "chown"

Comment: @Vladmir I don't have `requirements.txt` in my project directory

Comment: @Okolie did you check your permissions?

Comment: @Vladmir how do check permission using `chown` ?. I tried checking permission through the properties of the  folder and it appears I have `write` permission

Comment: @Okolie run **whoami** and then run **ls -ld "your_project_folder"** -> post results here

Comment: @Vladmir running the second command, I got this `drw-rw-rw-  4 8470p 0 4096 2021-09-28 09:29 my_project_folder`

Comment: @Okolie and the 1st command?

Comment: @Vladmir returns my root dir `chukypedro\8470p`

Comment: did you try run this command using "sudo"?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).